# Java Collision Detection Not Working

Tags: java

I have made threads in the past about similar questions but because of my lack of detail the answers have not really been related to what I needed so I am going to try explain my question in as much detail as I can and hopefully it will be easier for you to understand what I require.

I watched Bucky's slick game tutorials on youtube and made a 2D Java game, the game is basically a 2D player viewed from above (birds eye view) can move around a 2D map with user key input (up, down, left, right). The map the player moves around is very small so that meant boundaries had to be set so that the player could not walk off of the map, to give you a better idea of how this was done, here is the tutorial for setting up the voundries:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FgGRHId8Fn8

The video will also show you exactly what the game is like. 
The problem is, these boundaries only require one axis meaning that if the player is walking down you say something like "if player gets to the coordinate (number) on the X axis change the player movement to the opposite direction so that he can not go any further." 
Now this creates a problem for me because this only requires one axis so it easy to set up and understand but if you look on the video, on the map there is a house and I want my player not to be able to walk over that also but this deals with 2 dimensions, I have looked at things like rectangle collisions and have seen things relating to them in the other posts but I get confused because I am new to Java and havent really done much with it at the moment apart from watching Bucky's tutorials.

My code at the moment for my game class has got the following methods: init, render and update. So to sum it up I really just want to set up a way of not letting my player walk through the house, I will mention also (I should have mentioned it in my other threads) as I am very new to Java, could you please take a step by step method of showing me how to set up the collisions, I mean even the basics of things like making the rectangle if required.

If my code is required please tell me and I will post it as soon as possible.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Two possible options:

1. Extend `Shape` or `Rectangle` or the relevant Slick objects (they should exist IMO) and just check for `intersect()`
2. Look for `(x1,y1)` and `(x2,y2)` values such that it starts outside and ends up inside.

Assuming you have intersect() methods:

```
//Grab the previous position
prevPosX = movingobject.X;
prevPosY = movingobject.Y;
//Update the position
movingobject.update();

//Test for collision
if(movingobject.intersects(targetobj)) {
    //If it collided, move it back 
    movingobject.X = prevPosX;
    movingobject.Y = prevPosY;
    //And reverse the direction 
    //(might want to do other stuff - e.g. just stop the object)
    movingobject.speed *= -1;  //Reverse the speed
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but could you please tell me what the if statement would look like after I make the two rectangles intersect? I mean, how would I tell java that if it does intersect then stop it from going any further into the other rectangle?

Comment: I am sorry but I do not understand how to implement the code you have written into my game code, I understand how your code works as you have done a great job explaining it with the comments but I dont think it works with my code because your code is getting the X and Y coordinates from a variable but in my code the variables are already coorinates, I have attached my code to help you understand what I mean, the buckyPositionX and buckyPositionY are the variables that already hold the X, Y coordinates but when I try to change your code to fit mine I get loads of errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up the board as a 2x2 grid of a class that has has property such as 'isBlocked'. By default the edges of the board would have this property set to true to prevent the character from walking off the edge. When you add other obstacles such as a house or a wall the grid position(s) the object occupies would also have the property set to true. Then when moving a character you just check if the grid position the character moves to has the property set to false to see if it's an allowable move. This also makes it quite trivial to save the level data so you can just load them from disk later on.

Answer (score 0):

in this case your update class should also add one more condition to look for the house. let say the cooridnates of house(assuming rectanglular house here for other shape just change x and y values) are (x1,y1)(x1,y2)(x2,y2)(x3,y1) you have to add a condition to make sure
x value is not between x1 and x2 and at the same time y value cannot between y1 and y2.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply to my question. I understand the theory behind what you are saying but just don't understand how to code it, if you have the time could you please show me how this code would be written.

Comment: you can use the basic condition to check x and y something like:   if((x<x1)&&(x>x2))&&((y<y1)&&(y>y2))

Comment: Also check from which direction the object is colliding. Lets say the person is coming from the top so in this case the above condition will lead to something like:  if((x>x1)&&(x<x2)) x=x1;    if ((y>y1)&&(y<y2)) y=y1; similarly use for other directions.